# form design in web2py

Tags: forms, web2py

Is there a way to change a form that looks like this:
[image]

to a form that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You can design form by using any framework and with `custom form` method.

Comment: hi i tried with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43303715/web2py-custom-form-doesnt-submit

Comment: What issues you are facing with this?

Comment: Am not able to update the db from the textarea

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: It's in the above link. Regards

Comment: Provide name `attribute` with your `textarea` element and submit after that. Something like this `<textarea name="message"></textarea>`. Keep name attribute match with your table column name.