# web2py custom form doesn't submit

Tags: forms, web2py

I cant seem to submit my form with this code:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def index():
    db.post.answers.writable=False
    db.post.answers.readable=False
    form = SQLFORM(Post, formstyle='divs')
    if form.process().accepted:
        pass
    code.....
    return(form=form)
```

view:

```
{{=form.custom.begin}}
<div class="chat-form">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button>Send</button>
</div>
{{=form.custom.end}}
```

My db is empty with no data submitted.Please help
Regards

Comment: No luck yet. Still not working, same code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify "name" attributes for your HTML input elements, and if you are using `SQLFORM` with a web2py `DAL` model, the input names must match the names of the model fields. So, in the example you have shown, you would need:

```
<textarea name="answers"></textarea>
```

Without the "name" attribute, the browser will not send the data. And if the name does not match any fields in the `DAL` model, web2py will not do anything with the submitted data.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the information. And to you too @antony